# How to pass my excel sheet value to my sql query

Tags: excel, vba

I want to pass value from excel sheet to where condition of my sql query 
in place of `date_of_month = '2019-05'` should be `date_of_month='excel_sheet["A1"]'`

```
select date_of_month,studentname from student where date_of_month='2019-05'
```

Below is my code which I have tried but not working

```
Dim dateofmth as String
dateofmth = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
select date_of_month,studentname from student where date_of_month='"&dateofmth&"'
```

Comment: Please note that *"not working"* is a completely useless error description. If my answer below doesn't fix your issue please [edit] your question and show the **exact** code you use (make sure spaces and line breaks are at the same positions). Then describe which errors you get and in which line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have spaces around the `&` signs. Something like the following should work:

```
Dim DateOfMonth As String
DateOfMonth = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

Dim SqlQuery As String
SqlQuery = "Select date_of_month, studentname from student where date_of_month='" & DateOfMonth & "'"
```

Comment: Don't VBA correct automaticly this kind of issue or set the code line in Red ?

Comment: @Dorian It won't correct it because `Var&` is a valid syntax but in this case the `&` doesn't mean concatenation of strings. Instead it means to declare the variable as `Long` (like `Dim Var&` and `Dim Var As Long` is the same). But in case of what the OP did, it would produce a compile error (red line). Since the OP just said *"not working"* that could also be a red line compile error. • Conlusion: spaces are important in VBA and may change the meaning of the code.